# Generating JWT Tokens in Java for Token based Apple APNS Push notifications

Tags: java, jwt, apple-push-notifications

I am using Java code and generating JWT Tokens by providing .p8 file, Key Id and App Id. With the generated token I am able to decode the JSON as per inputs. However, I can not validate the signature using my .p8 File as private Key.

Also I am getting

> {"reason":"ExpiredProviderToken"}

from apple server even though token is generated and "iat" is 45 minutes more than current time.

Comment: *validate the signature using my .p8 File as private Key.* -  tokens are signed using the private key, but verified with the public key. - *"iat" is 45 minutes more than current time* - iat is issued at and supposed to be the time the token was issued. That can't be a time in the future. Expiration is determined by the exp claim, and that should be greater (later) than the iat.

Comment: Hi Jps, thanks for your response, if iat is set to current time, iam getting {"reason":"BadDeviceToken"}.